# call js in html.tpl.php

Tags: theming, javascript

I want to add smoothstate script to my pages. 
I have to call 2 files at the bottom just before closing body-tag. Smoothstate.js and Functions.js. How can I call those 2 js in my html.tpl.php

```
<script src="js/jquery.smoothState.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

[Smoothstate.js](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/)

Comment: Are you asking how to add the call to your tpl file, or are you asking how to fire off the functions of these .js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too simple my friend. For these types of manipulations [template_process_html(&$variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) comes handy. This is provided by [theme.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/7) located in includes/ folder of your drupal directory.

You can put this function in your template.php file of your custom theme directory

```
/**
 *Implementing template_process_html()
 */

function custom_theme_process_html(&$variables) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('theme','custom_theme');
    $variables['scripts'] .= '<script src="' . $path . '/js/jquery.smoothState.js"></script>
<script src="' . $path . '/js/functions.js"></script>';
}
```

> This will append these new scripts to your scripts variables that is rendered to `html.tpl.php` as `<script>` tags while processing it. Provided that you put these scripts in the js folder located in your theme folder . So the file path should be like this - `sites/all/custom/themes/custom_theme/js/functions.js`.

Don't forget to `clear the cache` as its a `new hook` in your `template.php` file and drupal won't execute that hook until you do that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the script available on every page and you are creating your own theme or sub theme, then you might as well add it to your theme.info file like this :

```
scripts[] = js/jquery.smoothState.js
```

more information about the .info file formatting here https://www.drupal.org/node/171205

But if you only want it to appear on a certain page you can use a preprocess function with some logic to decide when it should be called like this :

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 99) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/jquery.smoothState.js', 'file');
  }
}
?>
```

However, as you stated you want them to be called at the bottom of the page, it is important that you state that in the drupal_add_js() call like this :

```
<?php
drupal_add_js($theme_path.'/js/jquery.smoothState.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer')); ?>
?>
```

then it will be called in the footer rather than in `<head>`

There are plenty of example on the drupal_add_js docs page https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7